# Sql Server Greater than and equals date

Tags: date, stored-procedures, getdate

I have dates in database.

```
2013-12-28 00:00:00.000
2013-12-28 00:00:00.000
```

I wrote a stored procedure for matching `Datetime.Now` and my database rows.

My stored procedure

```
Alter PROCEDURE SP_MATCH_DATE
   (
     getdate() ( Year-Month-Day)
   )
AS
BEGIN  
   SELECT *
   FROM MY_TABLE WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE 
      Dates = getdate() and Dates > getdate() 
END
```

I want to set `@DATETIME_NOW` from `getdate()`. After that I want to match `getdate()` to `Dates` (Year-Month-Day) and `getdate() > Dates`

Thanks.

Comment: I want to get datetime now as (Year-Month-Day) after that I want to match datetime(Year-Month-Day) equals and greater than "Dates"

Comment: ok check question again

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what you are asking, did you mean:

```
WHERE
    Dates >= cast(getdate() as Date)
```

Casting to datatype `Date` removes the time portion (be aware that casting on the date column will probably rule the use of any appropriate index. Unless the table is very large, it should not be an issue, as you are performing a `select *` anyway)

[Also, please note: `Dates` is not a good name for a column.]

Comment: Yes this is what i want . But Getdate must be only (Year-Month-Day) format. After that    Dates >= getdate(). How can i get datetime now as year month day ?